# Como inserir onCreateOptionsMenu em uma classe Java?

Tags: android

Como inserir o `onCreateOptionsMenu` e o `onOptionsItemSelected` dentro de uma classe Java para não ficar repetindo em todas as Activity que chamam ela ?

Eu tenho que passar só os ids e as classes que chamo ao clicar no item do menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

MenuInflater MenuItem = getMenuInflater();
// Aqui deve-se passar o xml como parametro da função para a outra classe
MenuItem.inflate(R.menu.novo_menu,menu); 

return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.id_c:

         // Aqui deve-se passar as 2 classes pela função para colocar no Itent
         Intent tela = new Intent(Tela1.this, tela2.class);
         startActivity(tela);
         break;

    case R.id.id_s:
        // Aqui deve-se passar as 2 classes pela função para colocar no Itent
        Intent tela = new Intent(Tela1.this, tela3.class);
        startActivity(tela);
        break;
}


return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Eu creio que o que você realmente deve fazer é ter uma activity pai e carregar seu layout em fragments, seria mais simples, não?

Comment: Ou caso queira manter as activitys e colocar por exemplo, funções diferentes para cada item em diferentes activitys, você pode colocar uma interface que chama um método na sua activity quando por exemplo um item é escolhido, nele vc passa como parâmetro o id pra fazer a comparação

Comment: Mas ainda acho a solução dos fragments mais apropriada para esse caso

Comment: @Woton Sampaio, você pode dar um exemplo de como fazer isso usando  fragments ? Não sabia que podia fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu disse, caso use fragments, todos eles irão ter a activity pai, nela você implementa os 2 métodos, se caso para cada `fragment` você queira que os `options` tenham uma função diferente, você pode fazer assim:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(tal_fragment.isVisible()){
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.item1:
              //Seu código
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }else if(outro_fragment.isVisible()){
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.item1:
                    //Seu código
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Viu? Dependendo de qual `fragment` está aberta no momento, os itens tem funções diferentes. Não sei se é bem isso que você quer, mas dê um feedback.

Se o que você quer é apenas que seu `NavigationDrawer` e seu `Menu` fiquem visíveis em todos `fragments`, é a mesma coisa, porem creio que suas funções serão as mesmas, esses métodos você implementa na activity pai.

Comment: Acho que não é bem isso, pois só tenho um menu que chamo em várias Activity, a diferença é que quando clico no item ele chama uma tela diferente no Intent. Mas os itens são o mesmo. O que eu queria era jogar isso em uma classe e instanciar essa classe na Activity que tiver o menu pra não ficar repetindo código.

Comment: Pq criar activitys? Vc deve usar fragments nesse caso como eu falei

Comment: Por que são várias activitys, que tem menu. O menu é só uma parte dela, mas as activitys são totalmente diferentes umas das outras só o menu que é igual. Mas vou dar uma pesquisada mais aprofundado nessa questão de fragments.